# Symfony2 Form custom field type with more than 1 field

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Struggling with Symfony2 Forms. The User object has a property of class Location. The form needs to display the Location in 2 select boxes: Country, City. (Later the city select box will be updated through ajax).

Tried using data transformers and events but couldn't find a way out, just got more confused.
Any hint on what steps to take to make that work?

```
// User class
class User
{
     ...
     protected $location;
}    

// LOCATION class
class Location
{
        ...
        protected $city;
        protected $country;
}


// User TYPE
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    ...
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        ...
        $builder->add("location", new LocationType);
    }
}

// CUSTOM Location FORM TYPE
class LocationType extends AbstractType
{
....
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add("country", "choice");
        $builder->add("city", "choice");


    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but where is the error? Cause from this amount of code, i don't see any problem.

Comment: There's no error. I need some hints what to do next to make it work.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html Here is the documentation about what you're doing, embeding form ? isn't it ?

Comment: The Location entity makes country & city `choice` fields, which suggests there should be a list of available choices (i.e., City and Country entities).  Wouldn't it make more sense for them to be text boxes? Or do you intend to restrict the location?  Location should be treated as suggested by @Jahnux73.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a day of reading documentation I found a very helpful video by Bernhard Schussek. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q80b9XeLUEA

After watching it twice figured out how to do the requirement.

- Model Data is of type Location
- Normalized data is of type array
- Made a data transformer which transforms the Location object into the array which keys correspond to the field names in the custom field type (country, city).

The data transformer was applied to the whole custom type object:

```
$builder->addModelTransformer(new LocationToArrayTransformer());
```

- The country field is added and prepopulated in buildForm
- The city field is added and prepopulated within an event listener which is triggered on PRE_SET_DATA. It also checks the value of country and based on that prepopulates the citites:

  $builder->addEventListener(
  \Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, 
  function(FormEvent $event) 
  {

  ```
   $cities = array(); // prepopulate here using a service, etc.

   $event->getForm()->add("cityId", "choice", array("choices" => $cities));
  ```

  });
- Using jQuery added the functionality to update the cities select dynamically using ajax.